# Edit a given cell in a series of excel workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large number of Excel files. These files I want to add a sequence of numbers (1500, 1501,...) in a specific cell.

For example, I want cell A2 for file name "Day1" to be 1500, same cell on the next file to be 1501, etc.

Is this possible using VBA?

Comment: What do you mean by `file number Day1`?  The implication is that you want to "number" your files in a specific sequence.  What is that sequence?  Is it, for example, Filename or Date file last updated?  If your file names are "01-02-2012.xls" (01 and 02 being day and month in sequence of your choice), you will have to sort the file list.  None of this is particularly difficult but you need to explain your requirement more clearly.

Comment: I'm sorry this should be File name not number ... :D .. so what I'm trying to do add sequence like 1501,1502,1503 ... etc in specific cell for workbooks on same folder

Comment: To be clear. (1) You want "A.xls" to  have sequence 1500, "B.xls" to have sequence 1501, "BZ.xls"  to have sequence 1502 and so on. (2) This is for every XLS file in a particular folder.  New question: Is it always the same worksheet?

Comment: Yes Tony the same worksheet and the same cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I create a macro that looks as though I might use it again, I save a copy as a text file in a resources folder.  I have found some routines that together should solve your problem.

I assume you will create a new workbook into which you will place the code below.  This workbook will not be updated.

The following routine takes three parameters:

- PathCrnt: The name of the folder to be searched for files.
- FileSpec: Identifies the pattern of the file names required.  "*.*" means all files.  "*.xls" means all files with an extension of "xls".  "File*.txt" means all files that start "File" and an extension of "txt".
- FileNameList: an array of strings in which names of matching files are stored.

I have simplified this routine a little to remove facilities that you do not require.

```
Sub GetFileNameList(ByVal PathCrnt As String, ByVal FileSpec As String, _
                                            ByRef FileNameList() As String)

' This routine sets FileNameList to the names of files within folder
' PathCrnt that match FileSpec.  It uses function Dir$() to get the file names.
' I can find no documentation that says Dir$() gets file names in alphabetic
' order but I have not seen a different sequence in recent years

  Dim AttCrnt As Long
  Dim FileNameCrnt As String
  Dim InxFNLCrnt As Long

  ReDim FileNameList(1 To 100)
  InxFNLCrnt = 0

  ' Ensure path name ends in a "\"
  If Right(PathCrnt, 1) <> "\" Then
    PathCrnt = PathCrnt & "\"
  End If

  ' This Dir$ returns the name of the first file in
  ' folder PathCrnt that matches FileSpec.
  FileNameCrnt = Dir$(PathCrnt & FileSpec)
  Do While FileNameCrnt <> ""
    ' "Files" have attributes, for example: normal, to-be-archived, system,
    ' hidden, directory and label. It is unlikely that any directory will
    ' have an extension of XLS but it is not forbidden.  More importantly,
    ' if the files have more than one extension so you have to use "*.*"
    ' instead of *.xls", Dir$ will return the names of directories. Labels
    ' can only appear in route directories and I have not bothered to test
    ' for them
    AttCrnt = GetAttr(PathCrnt & FileNameCrnt)
    If (AttCrnt And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
      ' This "file" is a directory.  Ignore
    Else
      ' This "file" is a file
      InxFNLCrnt = InxFNLCrnt + 1
      If InxFNLCrnt > UBound(FileNameList) Then
        ' There is a lot of system activity behind "Redim Preserve".  I reduce
        ' the number of Redim Preserves by adding new entries in chunks and
        ' using InxFNLCrnt to identify the next free entry.
        ReDim Preserve FileNameList(1 To 100 + UBound(FileNameList))
      End If
      FileNameList(InxFNLCrnt) = FileNameCrnt
    End If
    ' This Dir$ returns the name of the next file that matches
    ' the criteria specified in the initial call.
    FileNameCrnt = Dir$
  Loop

  ' Discard the unused entries
  ReDim Preserve FileNameList(1 To InxFNLCrnt)

End Sub
```

The following macro is not a complete solution.  However, I suggest you ensure that this bit is working before looking at the more complete solutions below.  This routine uses GetFileNameList to get a list of the XLS files in the same directory as the workbook containing this macro.  It then outputs that list to the Immediate Window.  Make sure that the list is as you require before continuing.  Note the `Option Explicit` statement must go at the top of the module.

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateWorkbooks()

  Dim FileNameList() As String
  Dim InxFNLCrnt As Long
  Dim PathCrnt As String

  If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
    ' It is easy to get into a muddle if there are multiple workbooks
    ' open at the start of a macro like this.  Avoid the problem until
    ' you understand it.
    Call MsgBox("Please close all other workbooks", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' For my testing, I placed the workbook containing
  ' this code in a folder full of XLS files.
  PathCrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

  Call GetFileNameList(PathCrnt, "*.xls", FileNameList)

  For InxFNLCrnt = 1 To UBound(FileNameList)
    Debug.Print FileNameList(InxFNLCrnt)
  Next

End Sub
```

The code below goes just before the `End Sub` of `Sub UpdateWorkbooks`.  It opens each Excel workbook and outputs it name and the name of the first worksheet to the Immediate Window.  Again I suggest you ensure this is working before continuing.

```
  Dim SeqNum as long
  Dim WBookOther As Workbook

  SeqNum = 1500   

  For InxFNLCrnt = 1 To UBound(FileNameList)
    If FileNameList(InxFNLCrnt) = ActiveWorkbook.Name Then
      ' Ignore this workbook
    Else
      Set WBookOther = Workbooks.Open(PathCrnt & FileNameList(InxFNLCrnt))
      With WBookOther
        ' ### When you add the next block of code, I suggest you
        ' delete this Debug.Print.
        Debug.Print FileNameList(InxFNLCrnt) & "   " & .Sheets(1).Name

        ' ##### The next block of code will go here #####            

      .Close SaveChanges:=False  ' Close the workbook without saving again
      Set WBookOther = Nothing   ' Clear reference to workbook
      End With
    End If
  Next
```

I do not want to update my workbooks nor do I wish to create a set of test workbooks so the code below has not been tested.  It is simple so I should have got it right first time but I would still test it carefully.  I suggest you create a Test folder to which you copy the workbook containing the code in this answer and one of your Excel workbooks.  Note: copy not move!  Test the macro with that one Excel workbook.  When you are happy with the way the first of your workbooks is handled, copy a second workbook and test again.  If the macro handles two workbooks correctly, it should handle any number.  However, I would save a copy of all the workbooks until you have used the Sequence numbers and they are performing as expected.

```
        With Sheets("xxxxx")    ' Replace "xxxxx" with the name of your worksheet 
          Debug.Print "Workbook " WBookOther.Name
          Debug.Print "  Cell A2 changed from [" & .Range("A2").Value & _
                      "] to [" & SeqNum & "]"  
          .Range("A2").Value = SeqNum
          SeqNum = SeqNum + 1   ' Ready for next workbook
        End With
        .Save           ' Save changed workbook
```

Best of luck.

Comment: @ nerdherd.  Thank you.  I seem to specialise in this type of answer because I have saved so many useful bits of code over the years.

Comment: Tony you are the best ... great work .. Thank u a lot 
I've test it and it works perfect . but what if I want sequence to be mix of numbers and letters ?

Comment: What sort of mix of numbers and letters?

Comment: like No 1502 ... or invoice 1204?

Comment: `.Range("A2").Value = "No " & SeqNum` `.Range("A2").Value = "invoice " & SeqNum` You can set a cell to a number, string, date or whatever. `&` may be used to concatenate literals and variables together into a string of almost any length. If the result is a string, a numeric variable, such as `SeqNum` will be converted to a string so it can be included. Is this what you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but I don't believe there's a simple way to accomplish this. You would need to write some code in VBA (or really any language that has an Excel library) to open each workbook and update cell A2.

Check out [this](http://www.zerrtech.com/content/how-use-excel-vba-open-a-workbook-edit-save-and-close) example of some VBA that's relatively similar to what you're wanting to do. I've copied the relevant code example:

```
Sub WorkbooksLoop()    
    ' get the list of filenames
    Dim filenames() As String
    filenames = GetFilenames()

    ' an error will be thrown if there are no files, just skip loop and end normally
    On Error GoTo NoFilenames

    ' save a handle to the current workbook so we can switch back and forth between workbooks
    Dim controllerwb As Workbook
    Set controllerwb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim fname As Variant

    ' Find the current path for this file to use in opening workbooks in the same directory
    Dim rootPath As String
    rootPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    rootPath = rootPath & "\"

    For Each fname In filenames
        ' Make the controller active
        controllerwb.Activate

        On Error Resume Next
        ' If activate fails, then the workbook isn't open
        Workbooks(fname).Activate
        ' If activate fails, then the workbook isn't open
        If Err <> 0 Then
            ' open the workbook
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(rootPath & fname)
            ' then activate it
            wb.Activate
        ' Otherwise, workbook is already open, refer to it by name
        Else
            Set wb = Workbooks(fname)
        End If

        ' do something to the open workbook
        wb.Cells(1,1).Value = "Sweet!"

        ' Save and Close the workbook
        wb.Save
        wb.Close
    Next fname
NoFilenames:
End Sub
```

You would need to write a function called GetFilenames which returns an array of file names that you want to update for this example to work.

Comment: I do not understand `filenames = GetFilenames()`.  I cannot find such a function.  The nearest I can find is `GetFilename()` which requires a file system object and strips the path of a absolute file name.

Comment: That's not a standard function. You have to write it yourself to get the file names you want to update.

Comment: How was user1227516, or anyone else, supposed to guess that?

Comment: My apologies, I assumed that was clear from the example. I've edited the answer to mention it explicitly.

Comment: A common problem; what seems so obvious to you is obsure to others.  Problem solved with your edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code ... Thanks to Tony Dallimore

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetFileNameList(ByVal PathCrnt As String, ByVal FileSpec As String, _
                                            ByRef FileNameList() As String)
  Dim AttCrnt As Long
  Dim FileNameCrnt As String
  Dim InxFNLCrnt As Long

  ReDim FileNameList(1 To 100)
  InxFNLCrnt = 0

  ' Ensure path name ends in a "\"
  If Right(PathCrnt, 1) <> "" Then
        PathCrnt = PathCrnt & "\"
  End If

  ' This Dir$ returns the name of the first file in
  ' folder PathCrnt that matches FileSpec.
  FileNameCrnt = Dir$(PathCrnt & FileSpec)
  Do While FileNameCrnt <> ""
    ' "Files" have attributes, for example: normal, to-be-archived, system,
    ' hidden, directory and label. It is unlikely that any directory will
    ' have an extension of XLS but it is not forbidden.  More importantly,
    ' if the files have more than one extension so you have to use "*.*"
    ' instead of *.xls", Dir$ will return the names of directories. Labels
    ' can only appear in route directories and I have not bothered to test
    ' for them
    AttCrnt = GetAttr(PathCrnt & FileNameCrnt)
    If (AttCrnt And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
      ' This "file" is a directory.  Ignore
    Else
      ' This "file" is a file
      InxFNLCrnt = InxFNLCrnt + 1
      If InxFNLCrnt > UBound(FileNameList) Then
        ' There is a lot of system activity behind "Redim Preserve".  I reduce
        ' the number of Redim Preserves by adding new entries in chunks and
        ' using InxFNLCrnt to identify the next free entry.
        ReDim Preserve FileNameList(1 To 100 + UBound(FileNameList))
      End If
      FileNameList(InxFNLCrnt) = FileNameCrnt
    End If
    ' This Dir$ returns the name of the next file that matches
    ' the criteria specified in the initial call.
    FileNameCrnt = Dir$
  Loop

  ' Discard the unused entries
  ReDim Preserve FileNameList(1 To InxFNLCrnt)

End Sub



Sub UpdateWorkbooks()

  Dim FileNameList() As String
  Dim InxFNLCrnt As Long
  Dim PathCrnt As String

  If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
    ' It is easy to get into a muddle if there are multiple workbooks
    ' open at the start of a macro like this.  Avoid the problem until
    ' you understand it.
    Call MsgBox("Please close all other workbooks", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' For my testing, I placed the workbook containing
  ' this code in a folder full of XLS files.
  PathCrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

  Call GetFileNameList(PathCrnt, "*.xlsx", FileNameList)

  For InxFNLCrnt = 1 To UBound(FileNameList)
    Debug.Print FileNameList(InxFNLCrnt)
  Next

  Dim SeqNum As Long
  Dim WBookOther As Workbook

  SeqNum = 1604

  For InxFNLCrnt = 1 To UBound(FileNameList)
    If FileNameList(InxFNLCrnt) = ActiveWorkbook.Name Then
      ' Ignore this workbook
    Else
      Set WBookOther = Workbooks.Open(PathCrnt & FileNameList(InxFNLCrnt))
      With WBookOther
      With Sheets("sheet2")    ' Replace "xxxxxx" with the name of your worksheet'
          Debug.Print "Workbook"; WBookOther.Name
          Debug.Print "  Cell A6 changed from [" & .Range("A6").Value & _
                      "] to [" & SeqNum & "]"
          .Range("A6").Value = SeqNum
          SeqNum = SeqNum + 1   ' Ready for next workbook
        End With
        .Save           ' Save changed workbook

      .Close SaveChanges:=False  ' Close the workbook without saving again
      Set WBookOther = Nothing   ' Clear reference to workbook
      End With
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```